# How to encrypt url response in https

Tags: https

I'm building a model asset website, model data format is Javascript, users can use GET request to load model in browser. Because each model was paid, I want to encrypt model request in https, my intention is users can't see the model request's response string in Fiddler or Firebug. Is it possible to make it via https or any suggestion?

e.g. this is a model link, http://www.mywebsite.com/model/sofa.js, normally, in the response, users can see the detailed content in their local browser.

Thanks

Comment: Encrypt it from whom? Surely a user who has paid for it is entitled to it?

Comment: Encrypt this url response content for client users. Don't let user see this url's response in his browser